# Validating uniqueness of nested instance's attribute using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a polling system. I would like all options to be made unique, but only within their respective `Poll`. I'm using a `proc` to validate that they are not blank:

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['option'].blank? }
end
```

But I'm not sure how to validate their uniqueness. I tried doing it within the `Option` model but it's not rejecting duplicate options created through the `Poll` form's `f.fields_for`:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll

  validates_uniqueness_of :option, scope: :poll_id
end
```

Is it possible to do it with `proc`?

Answer (score 0):

Apply uniqueness validation upon option attributes like `validates_uniqueness_of :title, :other, scope: :poll_id`

Comment: Oops I should've been more clear. `:option` is an attribute of `Option`. But you're saying that validation should work even when the `Option` instance is created using `Poll`'s `f.fields_for :options`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any condition to that proc. So you could do query for that column and see whether any results are returned and reject if it they are.